# Query database with user's input symfony2 framework

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am currently working with forms on the Symfony2 MVC framework. I have a controller which renders a form in a HTML page. The form allows the User to submit information about a film of their choosing to a database.

```html
 /**
     * @Route("/practise", name="practise")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function practiseAction(Request $request)
    {
            $movie = new movie();
            $form = $this->createForm(new MovieType(),$movie);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if($form->isValid())
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($movie);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute("success");

            }else{

                return $this->render('default/practise.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                ));
            }
    }
```

**What I want to do now** is build a search field that enables the User to search for a film on my website. How do I take what the user enters into the search field and query the database to see if that film is on the database. Is it better to let another controller to handle this action separately.

If anyone has done this before then I would really appreciate any tip. Thanks.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html -see section 7.8.2. By Simple Conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the search functionality in your current controller just fine.

A quick look at [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql) will set you on the right track.

Basically you pass the user input as a parameter like so:

```
public function searchAction($userInput){
    //Your logic here
}
```

Then, exactly as shown in the docs, you formulate your query:

```
public function searchAction($userInput){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT m
         FROM AppBundle:Movie m
         WHERE m.title > :title'
    )->setParameter('title', $userInput);

    $movie = $query->getResult();

    //You render your view
}
```

There are many more optimal ways to achieve the same result though, so I advise to throughly read the docs.

Comment: thanks for the answer. When you created the searchAction above, how do you pass the $userInput parameter to the action. What would that piece of code look like where is it passed from?

Comment: Through a form submit and therefore through the routing:
`<form action="{{ path('route_you_defined_in_your_routing_file') }}">'`

And inside the searchAction function:

`public function searchAction(Request $request){
    //Typical form view setting
    $userInput = $form->getData();
}`

Read the docs about forms, it's well explained.